# How to get the last filled row in a specific column of a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automatically fill in the last row of a Google Sheet into a range from `C2:K{{last_row}}`. However, I am not sure how to proceed given my following code:

```
var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/sjhsak"; 
//make sure this includes the '
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form_Responses');
var values = sheet.getRange('C2:K{{last_row}}').getValues();
```

How would I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. To what range are you wanting to fill data, and from where?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your goal, but you must be looking for this:

```
sheet.getRange(`C2:K${sheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues();
```

If you want to store values starting from the last row and first column you could  do this:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)